# How to get comment of bug by TDAPIOLELib(HP Quality Center)

Tags: c#

How to get comment of bug by TDAPIOLELib? HP Quality Center Version: 9.2.
I am trying:

```
var tdc = new TDAPIOLELib.TDConnection();
tdc.InitConnectionEx("https://...");
tdc.Login("xxx", "yyy");
tdc.Connect("zzz", "vvv");

BugFactory bgf = tdc.BugFactory;
foreach (Bug bug in bgf.NewList(""))
{
   ...
}
```

But bug do not have Comment property.

There are alternatives(SOAP)?

Answer (score 2):

All bug, or any other QC entity, for that matter, fields can be accessed through the indexer object `Item[string fieldName]`.

In your case, to access the comment use

```
string bugComment = (string)bug["BG_DEV_COMMENTS"];
```

Comment: You have to be careful though when doing this. If a field is blank, then Nothing (or null) will be returned. Additionally, i have found out that not all columns in the table will be the same as the ones mentioned in the db documentation. That means, there can be no such column as `BG_DEV_COMMENTS`